# Excel VBA: Variable as First Row of Selection?

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a function in Excel VBA. I am trying to set a variable equal to the first cell in a selection on the worksheet. Basically the equivalent of something like

```
x = Worksheets("Data").Range("D2").Offset(i - 1, 0)
y = Worksheets("Data").Range("E2").Offset(i - 1, 0)
z = Worksheets("Data").Range("F2").Offset(i - 1, 0)
```

except I want "Range("D2")" E2 and F2 to instead refer to the first, second and third cell of whatever I've got highlighted on the sheet, rather than a preset cell.

The specific code I've got is:

```
Function VarunModel(Table As Range, Optional EndCondition As Integer = 0) As Variant
Dim iNumCols As Integer, iNumRows As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim SelectedRange As Range
Set SelectedRange = Selection


iNumCols = Table.Columns.Count
iNumRows = Table.Rows.Count

maturity = Worksheets("KMV-Merton").Range("B2").Value
For i = 1 To iNumRows
equity(i) = SelectedRange.Cells(1).Value
debt(i) = SelectedRange.Cells(2).Value
riskFree(i) = Selection.Cells(3).Value
Next i
Dim equityReturn As Variant: ReDim equityReturn(2 To iNumRows)
Dim sigmaEquity As Double
Dim asset() As Double: ReDim asset(1 To iNumRows)
Dim assetReturn As Variant: ReDim assetReturn(2 To iNumRows)
Dim sigmaAsset As Double, meanAsset As Double
Dim x(1 To 1) As Double, n As Integer, prec As Double, precFlag As Boolean, maxDev As Double
For i = 2 To iNumRows: equityReturn(i) = Log(equity(i) / equity(i - 1)): Next i
sigmaEquity = WorksheetFunction.StDev(equityReturn) * Sqr(260)
sigmaAsset = sigmaEquity * equity(iNumRows) / (equity(iNumRows) + debt(iNumRows))
NextItr: sigmaAssetLast = sigmaAsset
For iptr = 1 To iNumRows
x(1) = equity(iptr) + debt(iptr)
n = 1
prec = 0.00000001
Call NewtonRaphson(n, prec, x, precFlag, maxDev)
asset(iptr) = x(1)
Next iptr
For i = 2 To iNumRows: assetReturn(i) = Log(asset(i) / asset(i - 1)): Next i
sigmaAsset = WorksheetFunction.StDev(assetReturn) * Sqr(260)
meanAsset = WorksheetFunction.Average(assetReturn) * 260
If (Abs(sigmaAssetLast - sigmaAsset) > prec) Then GoTo NextItr
Dim disToDef As Double: disToDef = (Log(asset(iNumRows) / debt(iNumRows)) + (meanAsset - sigmaAsset ^ 2 / 2) * maturity) / (sigmaAsset * Sqr(maturity))
Dim defProb As Double: defProb = WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(-disToDef)

VarunModel = defProb
```

End Function

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code

```
Dim SelectedRange As Range
Set SelectedRange = Selection

x = SelectedRange.Cells(1).Value
y = SelectedRange.Cells(2).Value
z = SelectedRange.Cells(3).Value
```

Comment: When I try this, it seems to work, but it says that there's a circular reference. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tested this and worked absolutely fine for me. Did you do a selection and then run the code ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, now when I try to do it, I just get a circular reference error - should I only have a row selected and not a full table?

Comment: You can select a table too. It will start counting from the top left and once a row is finished, it will move to next column. i.e Cells(3) in a 2X2 represents the first cell in the second row.

Comment: I have it as part of a loop, could that be a reason why it's giving me a circular reference? I'll edit the post to show the exact code if that clarifies things.

Comment: Even if used in a loop it should work fine. In which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: Within the spreadsheet: when I enter the function and select an area, it gives me a warning saying there's a circular reference, and returns a value of 0.

Comment: The error is not due to the piece of code that we added. Check http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/09/16/excel-circular-references/ article on how to resolve circular reference error.

Comment: Hmm, I've enabled Iterative Calculations in the options, which makes sense given the model, but now it returns a #VALUE error - something else must be wrong in my code. I appreciate all your help very much.

Comment: If you don't mind, any idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: It is difficult to say without knowing about your data. Can you narrow down to where exactly it throws error ?

Comment: This line appears to cause the function to restart: equityReturn(i) = Log(equity(i) / equity(i - 1)) and is the cause of the warning, but I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: I think either equity(i) or equity(i-1) might be zero causing the issue. try running in debug mode and find exactly which data is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Dim Row as integer
Dim Col as Integer
Row = 2
Col = 4  'column "D"
x = Worksheets("Data").cells(row, col).Offset(i - 1, 0)
col = col + 1
y = Worksheets("Data").cells(row, col).Offset(i - 1, 0)
col = col + 1
z = Worksheets("Data").cells(row, col).Offset(i - 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the example below for using the selection on the excel, you can control the column you want by changing the column index. If you select only 1 cell, it will also work:

```
Sub Solution()

     x = Selection.Cells(1, 0) 'By using the zero index on the column, it will get the left cell from the selected one.
     y = Selection.Cells(2, 0)
     Z = Selection.Cells(3, 0)

End Sub
```